# What does get to mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Gorilla babies and elephant babies and human babies are not so different, except that a gorilla gets to spend the day riding on his mother's back.

What does get to mean in this sentence?

Comment: Those who considered this GR may please cite a standard reference, after having verified its relevance and sufficiency.

Comment: For starters, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get#Verb, meaning 13.

Answer (score 2):

[get to (do something)](http://www.idiomconnection.com/gquiz.html#A1)

> - to have a chance to do something, to be able to do something
>     *I did not get to go to the circus last week.*

… a gorilla **has the privilege to** spend the day riding on his mother's back (which an elephant baby doesn't).